# duplicate soap request posted from web-logic server in response receive time out

Tags: java, spring, soap-client, weblogic12c

I have deployed jaxws ri soap client on web-logic 12c, in case of response recive time out duplicate request is getting posted, find the following code snippet

```
public String getAuthZResponse(MerchantWebServiceSoap serviceSoap, String  
 strCmd, String strXML, int time)  
            throws InterruptedException,  
                ExecutionException
    {
        String response = "";
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new AuthZTask(serviceSoap, strCmd, strXML));// strCmd stands for command in soap request

        try
        {
            response = future.get(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);// time out here is 25 seconds
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            response = "Response time out!!";
            future.cancel(true);
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
        return response;

    }  
class AuthZTask implements Callable<String>
{

    String strCmd = null, strXML = null;
    MerchantWebServiceSoap serviceSoap = null;

    public AuthZTask(MerchantWebServiceSoap serviceSoap, String strCmd, String strXML)
    {
        this.strCmd = strCmd;
        this.strXML = strXML;
        this.serviceSoap = serviceSoap;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception
    {
        String authorizeResponse = serviceSoap.callPaySecure(strCmd, strXML);
        return authorizeResponse;
    }

}  
// jax rs soap client for action
@WebMethod(operationName = "CallPaySecure", action = "third party end point goes here")
    @WebResult(name = "CallPaySecureResult", targetNamespace = "third party end point namepsace goes here")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "CallPaySecure", targetNamespace = "third party end point namepsace goes here", className = "CallPaySecure")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "CallPaySecureResponse", targetNamespace = "third party end point namepsace goes here", className = "CallPaySecureResponse")
    public String callPaySecure(
        @WebParam(name = "strCommand", targetNamespace = "third party end point namepsace goes here")
        String strCommand,
        @WebParam(name = "strXML", targetNamespace = "third party end point namepsace goes here")
        String strXML);
```

But when the same code is executed from tomcat server then the request is getting posted once only. The call made is Server to Server.
help about the same at earliest, 
thanks in advance